# Openpyxl not using formula correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am currently using the following python code to put the formula in each cell while updating the cell number:

```
for i in range(3, 202):
    ws['C{}'.format(i)].value = "=AVERAGE('*Location to file*'!E{0}, '*Location to file*'!H{0}, '*Location to file*'!E{0}, '*Location to file*'!H{0}, '*Location to file*'!E{0}, '*Location to file*'!H{0})".format(i)
```

But all I am getting in Excel is #Div/0! error. If I manually put the exact code into Excel I get the value I am looking for.

Comment: How does your formula from excel look like? What use is * before/after "Location to file"?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. the "Location to file" is just what I put in Stack Overflow as I did not want to copy over the location to the web. all the "Location to file" is because the data is in a different spreadsheet to what I am working with, it also spans over several tabs in Excel.

Comment: Does any of the cell you refer contain blank or non-numeric values? You can use  `ws['C{}'.format(i)].Formula = "=AVERAGE(.....)"`. Another optimization could be write formula on one cell and copy it to rest of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

From answers.microsoft.com
AVERAGE ignores empty cells, as well as cells with text such as the null string ("").  To avoid a #DIV/0 error, you must be sure there is at least one number to average.

Also the values must be numeric and not text.

You must have a string conversion error somewhere

Comment: I understand how excel works, I know the AVERAGE ignores empty cell and that is why I am doing it in excel and not averaging it in python the pasting the result into the cells, because python does not ignore empty cells.

Comment: Correct.  What I was trying to indicate is that whatever you are placing in the average formula is evaluating as a string. ```'*Location to file*'!E{0}``` is probably being interpreted as a string by excel and not as a reference to a file path.  This may be due to using single quotes in the excel expression.  Remember, when you enter data directly into excel it has a tendency to 'be helpful'.   Enter00983  and excel will cheerfully convert it to 983.  You may have to use triple double quotes for the entire string and double quotes in the formula """=Average("'*Location to file*'!E{0}" ....)"""

Comment: That just causes a #value error, I really am stumped but I think it might be an Excel issue because if I have a the same spreadsheet open but with the formula filled in manually (the spreadsheet does not even have to be saved) my python works fine, but as soon as I close the other spreadsheet it breaks again :(